# heroku app - crashed on sign in

Tags: mysql, sql, heroku, go, cleardb

I'm trying to get my app running on Heroku. I built my program in Go. I'm using clearDB for my SQL database.

Heroku displays the first page of my web app, which is a login page. However, when I enter the username and password to sign up, an "Application Error" notice is displayed on the page. This is the error msg when I ran Heroku logs:

```
2014-08-21T16:22:21.444654+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-08-21T16:22:22.993357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `twitter`
2014-08-21T16:22:24.503757+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-21T16:22:21.231175+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by xxxx@gmail.com
2014-08-21T16:22:46.419654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-sierra-5001.herokuapp.com request_id=c6f5b0a6-b56a-425e-a359-ca3817b6e4bd fwd="118.200.62.108 ,220.255.1.18"dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=866
2014-08-21T16:22:47.195639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/log.css"host=stark-sierra-5001.herokuapp.com request_id=6360fc0e-c822-491d-89d2-663ce743ba04 fwd="118.200.62.108 ,220.255.1.18" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=889
2014-08-21T16:23:01.541153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/login" host=stark-sierra-5001.herokuapp.com request_id=31763bf8-0e4e-4fa9-903b-ff6b2eda9a31 fwd="118.200.62.108 ,220.255.1.18" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=503 bytes=1036
2014-08-21T16:23:01.530628+00:00 app[web.1]: Fatal error Default addr for network 'us-cdbr-iron-east-01.cleardb.net' unknown
```

I suspect its a database error. But nothing seems to be amiss with my database. What should I do?

Comment: Can you try using this as the address instead: `54.227.215.252`? It's just the IP address of `us-cdbr-iron-east-01.cleardb.net`

Comment: Also, according to [this](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/44), try configuring your HOST in the following format: `HOST = locahost:3306`

Comment: thanks, how do I configure?

Comment: I'm not sure (I've never used Heroku or Go before)

Comment: does it work locally?